# jQuery colorplugin stops CSS :hover working

Tags: jquery, css, colors, hover

I am using the jQUery [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color). I have an `li` element that, when hovered over, changes it's background color. It does this by using the standard `:hover` CSS pseudo class in the CSS file. This works fine, until I use the color plugin on it - the `:hover` effect just stops working when I 'pulse' the element using this code:

```
$(".elements").first()
              .delay(400)
              .css({ backgroundColor: '#eeeeee' })
              .animate({ backgroundColor: '#888888' }, 2000);
```

Can anyone suggest a solution so that, when the 'pulse' is displayed, the original `:hover` behaviour continues to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define the rule for `:hover` with `!important` so when the JavaScript sets the inline style, it will override it.

Comment: Thanks you :-D Such a simple answer - I was thinking it was going to be some massive piece of JS. +1

Comment: Good point on !important. Depending on the desired effect, OP can use !important (if hover is more important than effect) or my suggestion if he wants to see the animation even if hovering, but revert back to normal hover behaviour afterwards.

Comment: The animation only occurs once - it's applied to a new `li` element added after an AJAX call, so `!important` is fine :-)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to stop the animation and remove the inline styles - an example to get you started:

```
$(".elements").hover(function(){
  $(this).stop().removeAttr('style')},
function(){
  $(".elements").first().delay(400).css({backgroundColor: '#eeeeee'}).animate({backgroundColor: '#888888'}, 2000);
});
```

Alternatively you could do your css like this:

```
li:hover {
  background:red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the explicit background colour set on the element, which is overriding the CSS. At the end of your animation, clear out the background colour like this:

```
$(".elements").first()
    .delay(400)
    .css({backgroundColor: '#eeeeee'})
    .animate({backgroundColor: '#888888'}, 2000, function() {
        $(this).css({backgroundColor: ''});
    });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SyqSf/